# git deploy to an Azure website fails with "unknown error"

Tags: azure, azure-deployment

I've been successfully using Git deploy (via Kudu) to a couple of Azure websites (e.g., beta/prod) for several months, and it's worked quite well. Starting today, I noticed that when I push to the appropriate respective git branch to my beta website - but *not* to my production website - the deploy fails, with an "Unknown Error" in the console, and no errors of any sort in the deployment logs. Again, exactly the same deployment works to my production server, and I haven't changed anything on my beta server in-between when the deploys stopped working.

So far as I can tell from the logs, it's failing at this point in my deploy.cmd:

```
:: 1. Build to the temporary path
IF /I "%IN_PLACE_DEPLOYMENT%" NEQ "1" (
  %MSBUILD_PATH% "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\Payboard.Web\Payboard.Web.csproj" /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /t:pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:_PackageTempDir="%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%";AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Release /p:SolutionDir="%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\.\\" %SCM_BUILD_ARGS%
) ELSE (
  %MSBUILD_PATH% "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\Payboard.Web\Payboard.Web.csproj" /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Release /p:SolutionDir="%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\.\\" %SCM_BUILD_ARGS%
)

IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
```

This is the sort of thing that I'd normally contact Azure support for, but my subscription doesn't include tech support :-(. The Azure site recommends asking here on SO, and hence my post.

I've stopped and restarted the website, and poked around with the truly handy [KuduConsole](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console), but other than that, I'm kind of out of ideas.

Any suggestions for further troubleshooting this?

Comment: Try the following: Add an app settings called **SCM_TRACE_LEVEL** with the value **4**, try to redeploy and see if the extra traces helps, also are you using custom deployment script?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using a custom deploy.cmd. I think there were some weird things going on with Azure, as I started getting a whole bunch of other errors as well, including some (eventually) on my production site - things like, `Scm service error is "Response status code does not indicate success: 406 (Not Acceptable).` Or, `Insufficient resources available to perform the requested operation.` And then it all started working again. Not the first time that Azure's deployment infrastructure has given me fits.

Comment: If it's not a hassle, try regenerating the custom deployment script (with newest azure-cli/kuduscript version), it has better error output that helps you debug the failure